# Is it possible to $setOnInsert with aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

MongoDB has recently added an option to perform an `update` operation by providing an aggregation pipeline rather than the standard modifier object. [Check MongoDB's docs on this topic](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

The ability to use aggregation pipeline, whose statements can refer to existing document properties, can be extremely useful in situations when certain fields needs to be evaluated based on other fields, e.g. during data migration.

Moreover, most of the standard update operators like `$set`, `$push`, `$inc`, etc. can be successfully replicated with the aggregation expression language so in some sense this new functionality generalizes the good old modifiers technique. Though, I must admit the pipeline can become quite verbose if one tries to do things like `$addToSet`. This of course brings up a whole bunch of performance related questions, but let's ignore them for now.

So far, there's been just one thing which I haven't been able to fully replicate with the aggregation pipeline update, namely the `$setOnInsert` operator. Let's assume that I want to perform an upsert:

```js
db.test.update(selector, pipeline, { upsert: true });
```

My initial intuition was that the `$$ROOT` variable (which I can use in the `pipeline`) will equal `null` unless there exists a document that matches `selector`. Unfortunately, but probably for a good reason, MongoDB developers decided that `$$ROOT` should be derived from `selector` by default. It makes sense when you think about how normal `$setOnInsert` works, but it also makes it practically impossible to distinguish between an update and an insert within `pipeline`.

I know what you're thinking. You can look at `$$ROOT._id`. This is a good idea, though if `_id` is part of the `selector` it doesn't work anymore. I have figured out that this can be bypassed by tricking MongoDB a little bit and doing things like:

```
selector = {
  _id: { $in: [value, 'fake'] },
}
```

instead if the simpler `{ _id: value }`, but this doesn't look clean. Please note that if `$in` only contains one element, then Mongo is actually clever enough to figure out what the identifier should be and it populates `$$ROOT` accordingly (sic!).

I am wondering if anyone has a better idea how to approach this. Maybe there's some hidden variable that I could potentially use inside the `pipeline` itself to distinguish between `update` and `insert` (e.g. in `$merge` stage there's `$$new` variable which serves a similar purpose)?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no matching documents, `$$ROOT` will have only `_id` field. So you can transform `$$ROOT` to array by its key/value pairs and check if the size of that array is equal to 1. If it is then create a new document, and if it is not then do nothing.

- `$objectToArray` and `$size` to convert **$$ROOT** to an array by its key/value pairs and to get the size of that array
- `$cond` to check if the size of the array above is equal to 1. If it is then merge current **$$ROOT** (which is only **_id** field) with the **update** object. If it is not, return the current **$$ROOT**. In both scenarios, put result in **result** feild.
- `$mergeObjects` to merge **$$ROOT** and the **update** that you are sending, and put that in the **result** field
- `$replaceRoot` to replace root to the **result** field from previous stage

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      result: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            "$eq": [
              {
                $size: {
                  $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
                },
                
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$ROOT",
              {
                key: 3
              }
            ]
          },
          else: "$$ROOT"
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$result"
    }
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WBt0ZG5hGxX)

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here. In a more generic scenario, i.e. when `selector` also contains other fields than `_id`, the `$$ROOT` object will also have other fields as well and I could theoretically take them into account in a similar manner. Though, the problem I am facing is I would like to have a generic solution that works with any possible `selector`. And frankly, it seems quite difficult to figure out how exactly MongoDB maps `selector` to `$$ROOT` in general.

Comment: Maybe you can ask them directly.

Comment: I was actually hoping that they might be reviewing questions on StackOverflow tagged with `mongodb` :) But you're right that my post is probably better described as "feature request" for `v5.0` than a regular question.